# Запись результата перевода в txt или excel

Tags: python

В файле `myfile.txt` две строчки:

> A blessing in disguise, Better late than never.

Перевод в консоли.
Что ни пробовал, выдает ошибки при `writting` в `txt` или `excel`

```py
try:
    with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
            s = file.readlines()
    from googletrans import Translator

    translator = Translator()
    result = translator.translate(s, dest='ru', src="en")
    print(result[0].text+ " " + result[1].text)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Невозможно открыть файл")
finally:
    print(file.closed)
```

Решил продолжить:

Читаем из книги excel заносим результат в txt. Одна ошибка

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'closed'

Если я использую:

```py
finally:
    print(file.closed)
```

А так все хорошо.

**UPD:**

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Python_Youtube.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

# считываем значение определенной ячейки
val = sheet['B1'].value

# считываем заданный диапазон
file = [v[0].value for v in sheet['C1:C5']]
try:
    with open("myfile2.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as outfl:
        outfl.writelines([str(line) + "\n" for line in file])
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Невозможно открыть файл")
# finally:
#     print(file.closed)
```

Comment: Покажите код, как вы пробовали

Comment: А где ваш "writting" ?? Чтение вижу. Вывод в консоль - вижу. А запись в файл -  где?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде нет никакой записи результата. В первом блоке кода вы открываете файл в режиме **read-only** и считываете из него данные. Больше к файлу вы никак не обращаетесь.

Для того, что бы записать данные в файл, нужно иметь примерно вот такой код:

```py
try:
    # открытие файла для чтения
    with open("myfile.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            s = file.readlines()

    # перевод
    from googletrans import Translator
    translator = Translator()
    result = translator.translate(s, dest='ru', src="en")

    # вывод в консоль
    print(result[0].text+ " " + result[1].text)

    # запись в файл "out_result.txt"
    with open("out_result.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as outfl:
        outfl.write("\n".join(result))

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Невозможно открыть файл")
```

При этом обратите внимание на то, что в функции `open` нужно указывать так же аргумент `encoding`. Я указал распространенную кодировку `"utf-8"`, но если вы работаете под Windows, то возможно у ваших файлов кодировка `"cp1251"`. Если что-то не так будет с кодировками, то в файле с результатами вместо кириллицы вы получите кракозябры.

Comment: Спасибо. Я это и пытался вчера. Но excel лучше/ Запись данных в excel файл потом транслятор

Comment: Спасибо. Я это и пытался вчера. Но excel лучше/ Запись данных в excel файл удачно, потом транслятор Вот код {import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\........\study\\datafiles\\English_simple.xlsx')
# translate a column to ru, and add back into the DataFrame
translator = Translator()
df['Ru'] = df['text'].apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='ru').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
# output new excel file
df.to_excel('English_translate.xlsx') } Выдает ошибку:raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'text' Вроде просто. Как выделить код здесь?

Comment: Кстати, @cauf Ваш код рабочий, при данном условии: # запись в файл "out_result.txt" 
    with open("myfile2.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as outfl:
        outfl.writelines([str(line) + "\n" for line in result])

Comment: @ОлегНовосельцев 1. я ничего не понял. код не читаем. Добавьте ваш новый код в текст вопроса ниже, отбив меткой `UPD:` и не удаляйте предыдущий текст и код. Кнопка "править" сразу под метками (тегами) вопроса. 2. по поводу цикла - да, мой косяк. Я пропустил тот момент, что вы считываете построчно, а не одним массивом. Поправил свой код - обратите внимание, что то же самое можно сделать гораздо короче

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли. Что касается интеграции Интеграция MS Excel и Python, допустим есть какой-либо функция, которая обрабатывает данные на python, и нужно перенести ее функциональность в Excel - это темный лес. Нужно вкуривать. И vba знать. А что я хотел? Выгрузить данные из excel таблицы, обработать( перевести с en на ru) И обратно переписать в excel . Но это серьезная работа. Вот статья. буду вкуривать ) https://habr.com/ru/post/232291/

Comment: Решил преобразовать код, Брал данные из excel , запись избранного в txt. Но одна ошибка все же есть. Если удалить finally:
    print(file.closed) Все работает.

Comment: @ОлегНовосельцев 1. Если ответ решил вашу проблему - отметте его как решение. 2. `finally` в вашем случае не нужен совершенно. Оператор `with` создает ограниченную область видимости с контекстом работы буфера. То есть, файлы, открытые в рамках данного оператора, закрываются автоматически по выходу из соответствующего блока. В вашем случае, сразу после строки `s = file.readlines()` файл будет автоматически закрыт.

Comment: Может еще кто нибудь, что то добавит. Я не против. А вот как насчет нетривиальной задачи? : Пользователь вводит данные, которые записываются в excel файл в столбик  a: английские слова, далее данные выгружаются в python, где переводятся на русский, потом переведенные данные загружаются в столбик b. Кстати, у вас в профиле знание vba. Может вы что подскажите, по поводу методов трансляции файлов с eng на ru в excel, если такие существуют.

Comment: Сложно найти, где ставить метку, что вопрос решен?